# File that contains backspace sound

Tags: sound

What file gets played when you hit backspace in an empty entry field or at the prompt in a terminal window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg`.

Other options can be seen in the Sounds settings (Bark, Glass, Sonar, etc.) depending on which desktop, etc. is installed. These are also located in `/usr/share/sounds`. For example, with GNOME:

```
$ ls /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/                                                                                                                                                            
bark.ogg  drip.ogg  glass.ogg  sonar.ogg
```

Fishing around in `/usr/share/sounds`, the actual default if Ubuntu hadn't added their own would be `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga`.

(If you're not actually running a GUI, then it will be the system beep as mentioned in the other answer.)

Comment: Nope. I've already played every sound in /usr/share/sounds/* and nothing there matches what I hear on an empty-field backspace.

Comment: @PhilWolff what terminal emulator are you using? This is certainly the sound I have heard on Ubuntu 12.04 - 16.04. (Also, you played all ~90 files in that directory? :O)

Comment: Help/About says GNOME Terminal 3.24.2.

Comment: Yep - played every one of them, didn't hear what I was after, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: @PhilWolff add the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard` to the question please.

Comment: Also, `pactl list samples` and `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences | grep bell`

Comment: Ok, my misteak. Raising vlc's playback volume to max reveals that bell.ogg is indeed the sound I'm looking for. A vote for you!

Comment: @PhilWolff if an answer solved your question, please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a file, it is the system beep that you can also trigger by `echo -ne '\007'`.

Comment: Maybe I should have specified Ubuntu 17.10/Wayland. This shell command plays no sound for me.